# PNPM | 3 IF | If different projects use different versions of package, if libraries were installed through npm, if you use docker

Tags: npm, pnpm

I was wondering

- **If different projects use different versions of a package.** Does it
  make sense to use pnpm?
- **If libraries were installed through npm.** Can I use pnpm for
  installations other libraries or everything has to be reinstalled through
  pnpm?
- **If you use docker.** Does it make sense to use pnpm?